# Strange segmentation fault

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I've defined a random function (`int random(int sup, int seed)`) which returns a value between 0 and `sup-1`. 
I've defined a struct, point, of which pos_parents and population are 2-dimensional arrays.
The swap functions swap elements of the v array, which is a array of "indexes". All is done in order to sort out par_n members into pos_parents out of population members without sorting twice the same member.

This gives segmentation fault.

If I replace the variable `r` inside `population[v[r]][j]` with an explicit value, then it all functions. How is this possible? I've tried the random function and it doesn't seem to have any problem.

In addition, when segmentation fault occours, printf won't even activate for the first loop.

```
point population[pop_size][array_size];
point pos_parents[4*par_n][array_size];
int v[pop_size];

for (i=0; i<4*par_n;i++)
    v[i]=i;

for(t=0;t<time_limit;t++) //The cycle of life
{
    for(i=0;i<4*par_n;i++)
    {
        r=random(pop_size-i,i);
        printf("%d\t",r);

        for(j=0;j<array_size;j++)
        {
            pos_parents[i][j]=population[v[r]][j];
        }
        swap(&(v[r]),&(v[pop_size-1-i]));
    }
```

When executing i type 3(route locations-array size), 8(pop_size), 1(time limit), 1 (par_n)

This is the entire code (less than 150 lines), always insert 1 to time_limit, because I haven't still completed the cycle.
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByylOngTmkJddVZqbGs1cS1IZkE

P.S.
I'm trying to write an evolutionary algorithm, for route optimization

Comment: The first thing you should do when getting a segmentation fault, or other crash, is to run your program in a debugger. This will help you locate the place of the crash, as well as let you examine variables to help you see what might have caused the crash.

Comment: In your case you are probably accessing indexes outside one of the arrays.

Comment: Right. In the above code, I'd guess that the size of `v[]` is less than `4*par_n`. So the first for-loop is overwriting something important in the stack frame.

Comment: Beyond the debugger suggesion of @JoachimPileborg, you have not posted enough code to determine what might be happening. It's almost certain you are touching an array location that doesn't exist, but with no declarations (or even better a runnable example), we can't help.

Comment: If you've got `par_n` members, why are you using `4 * par_n` for the upper bounds on your arrays? That could be a major part of your trouble. The `printf()` typically won't send anything to the screen until a newline is printed, or until the print buffer is full. For debugging, either print to `stderr`, or print a newline (and optionally use `fflush(0)` to flush the output. I worry about you providing the seed to the random function each time. For the rest, please consider providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) — a Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compiling) Example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I've included some declarations and submitted the entire program. I'm using 4* because I need even numbers. I ask the user to give me the number of couples (of parents) he want every generation, the program randomly selects 2 times the couples needed (so four times single routes), order them and then select the best n_par couples among the one randomly selected. But this is a detail I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've never used a debugger (I'm working on ubuntu) I'll try looking up something. I'l also try giving a SSCCE now.

Comment: I was right to be worried about the `seed` parameter to `random()`. You should only call `srand()` once per program; you should _not_ call `srand()` each time before you generate a random number; it defeats the randomness (and `time()` is not a good source of randomness either). However, given the array definition I see why you have `4 * par_n` and indexing up to `4 * par_n` should not be the cause of the trouble.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, I've now corrected the problem. I runned srand() inside main with a seed I inserted.
What is a valid alternative to time? And why does this matter when the srand() is called ones per program?

Comment: It depends in part on what you're up to.  For cryptography, `time()` is useless (too predictable). For giving different results each time it is run, `time()` works adequately.  So, for simulations, `time()` is adequate (as long as you only seed once; if you seed each time you call, then you will get the same first number in the sequence until the time changes to the next second).

Answer (score 1):

The loop with `v[i] = i;` goes from `0` to `4 * par_n`, but `v` is an array of size `pop_size`. That looks like an out-of-bounds problem waiting to strike. And the same again for the counter `i` in `r = random(pop_size - i, i);`, since `i` is used in `v[i]`.

Comment: to jonathan and Kerrek. The i inside the random function is not disturbing, pos_size-i lower the bound inside which the random is working so that taken numbers are not taken again. In adition I give i to the seed cause I had a problem before where random was giving the same values until I inserted this index